# Put Integer in a nested Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, nested, object-reference

I have a nested Hashmap in this structure: `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Integer>>`. I'm trying to put data in this order:

```
{
item_id1 -> { {user_id1 -> rating} , {user_id2 -> rating} ...}
item_id2 -> ...
...
}
```

The problem is that wrong `user_id` gets inserted into wrong `item_id`, thus giving wrong rating. I think there is a problem with the object reference of the inner HashMap, but I'm not sure.

```
public HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> getUserRating() throws SQLException {

    HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Integer>> ratings = 
            new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM rating";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

    Integer rating;
    Integer user;
    Integer item;
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> innerHashMap =  null;
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        item = resultSet.getInt(2);
        user = resultSet.getInt(1);
        rating = resultSet.getInt(3);

        if(innerHashMap == null) {
            innerHashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        }
        innerHashMap.put(user, rating);
        ratings.put(item,innerHashMap);

    }

    // item_id = 400 , user_id = 44490. Should print rating = 4, but prints 2
    System.out.println(ratings.get(400).get(44490));

    return ratings;

}
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger.

Comment: Hint: How many times do you call `innerHashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();`? Do you call it once per item?

Comment: @JB Nizet Ok, I get your point. On the assumption that item_id is ordered, I now only create a new instance of the inner HashMap if there is a new item. But now I get a NULLPOINTER at `innerHashMap.put(user,rating);`

Comment: Don't make the ordering assumption. Get the inner HashMap associated to the current item from the enclosing ratings map. If it doesn't exist yet, create it and store it in the enclosing ratings map. Then put the new value in the inner map.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JB Nizet . This works:

```
    public HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> getUserRating() throws SQLException {
    HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Integer>> ratings = 
            new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM rating";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

    Integer rating;
    Integer user;
    Integer item;

    HashMap<Integer,Integer> innerHashMap =  null;
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        item = resultSet.getInt(2);
        user = resultSet.getInt(1);
        rating = resultSet.getInt(3);

        if(ratings.get(item) == null) {
            innerHashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        }

        innerHashMap.put(user, rating);
        ratings.put(item,innerHashMap);


    }

    // item_id = 400 , user_id = 44490. Should print rating = 4
    System.out.println(ratings.get(400).get(44490));

    return ratings;

}
```

Comment: That is still incorrect. Indeed, if ratings.get(item)  is not equal to null, you will add a rating to the inner HashMap associated to the previous item. It should be `innerHashMap = ratings.get(item); if (innerHashMap == null) { innerHashMap = new HashMap<>(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to re-create a new innerHashMap on each iteration.

Actually you just have one so you mix the values in it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove  `if` condition

```
if(innerHashMap == null) {
    innerHashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
}
```

Since you need a new HashMap for each item id , 
So You can create new `innerHashMap` every time

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
   item = resultSet.getInt(2);
   user = resultSet.getInt(1);
   rating = resultSet.getInt(3);
   innerHashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); <--- New Instance every time
   innerHashMap.put(user, rating);
   ratings.put(item,innerHashMap);
}
```

Comment: That is incorrect, I've tried that and I only get 1 user_id per item_id with this solution.

Comment: you will get only single one because at each iteration of database your item id is changing !!

Comment: if you need for 1 item id , multiple Map entries then you should fetch out all userId's with Rating for single item id , then add it !!